# disable dates in datepicker with orchard

Tags: javascript, jquery, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using orchard 1.6. I've created a form which uses a content type which uses a field (date and time), which allows the user to use a date picker to select the day.

Trouble is the user can select any date. I would like the date to be set for today, and the other dates disabled. How is this possible? thank you for replies

[image]

Comment: if today always will be selected then why even you display date picker ?

Comment: When I click on the text field 'date' the date picker automatically loads. Just to save user-error incase the user happens to select the wrong date when uploading....is it possible...where is the code for the datepicker stored?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know the location of the `DateTimeField` then just go to following directory :

```
  Orchard.Fields/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/DateTime.Edit.cshtml
```

but making change to orchard fields is not a good practice , cause your case is very special.the recommended way to do this is to create your own `EditorTemplate` and integrate `jquery-ui` `datepicker` in your Template view.